# Update "varchar2" column only if new record found

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to develop simple code for my project.

Where I am supposed to update table `books.PUBLISHER`. Here in `PUBLISHER` column we already have below values `'abc; pqr'` and I want to update it with `'pqr; xyz'` so my expected output will be `'abc; pqr; xyz'`.

```
update books SET PUBLISHER = PUBLISHER || '; ' ||'pqr; xyz'
where id = 1 and PUBLISHER  NOT LIKE '%pqr; xyz%';
```

My expected output will be `'abc; pqr; xyz'`.

Comment: you need to create an INSERT or UPDATE trigger on the books table

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro: Thanks for your time, But here trigger is not allowed. Restriction for the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Your current value of `publisher` contains the string `pqr`. Your requirement shows you don't want to duplicate that value. By appending your proposed solution will duplicate the `pqr` value.

You can avoid the duplication with a `replace()`:

```
update books 
SET PUBLISHER = replace(PUBLISHER, 'pqr', 'pqr; xyz')
where id = 1 
and PUBLISHER  NOT LIKE '%pqr; xyz%';
```

This will substitute `pqr; xyz` wherever `pqr` appears in the `publisher` column.

Comment: But input strings (in our case 'pqr; xyz') could be anything. It will not work dynamically. eg if the input string is 'abc; xyz or 'nmo; xyz ' then expected output should be  'abc; pqr; xyz' and  'abc; pqr; nmo; xyz ' respectively. Thanks

Comment: Ah, that's a lot trickier. This is the price of ignoring good data modelling and not even putting tables into first normal form.

Answer (score 0):

The following update statement should do the job:

```
update books b
   set publisher =
       (select listagg(publisher_part, '; ') within group(order by publisher_part)
          from (select regexp_substr(bb.publisher, '[a-z]+', 1, level) as publisher_part
                  from (select publisher from books where id = b.id) bb
                connect by regexp_substr(bb.publisher, '[a-z]+', 1, level) is not null
                union
                select 'lmn' as publisher_part --> your new "publisher" pattern
                  from dual))
 where id = 1; --> id to update
```

The inner select (`select regexp...`) scatters your publisher column in separate results

```
abc
pqr
xyz
...
```

After that, the new value `lmn`is added by `union select from dual` and finally the result is aggregated in the previous format by `listagg`.

Better solution, as APC already recommended, is a normalization of your table.